# lua (Syntax): Calling a function that returns more than 1 value, and using those values as arguments, but without extra lines of variable assignment?

Tags: syntax, lua

I have a situation where I need to call the following:

```
function xy(i)
return i,i+8
end
```

And use its output in another function.

```
function addition(x,y)
return x+y
end
```

Is there a way to get this to work more elegantly than writing it like:

```
i.e. i=10; x,y=xy(10); addition(x,y)--28
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
i.e. i=10; addition(xy(10)--where I somehow get two arguments here)
```

Both functions are generics used elsewhere, merging isn't viable, possible edits to what/how they return might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least as of [Lua 5.1](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html), the following works 'as requested'.

> When a function call is the last (or the only) argument to another call, all results from the first call go as arguments. [There are several examples using print.]

```
function xy(i)
    return i,i+8
end

function addition(x,y)
    return x+y
end


addition(xy(10)) -- 28
```

A more wordy way, that might be useful to decompose in similar cases needing a little bit more flexibility, is to convert the result to a table and then use `unpack` (added in 5.1). This approach is result -> table -> unpack -> arguments (per above).

```
addition(unpack({xy(10)})) -- 28
```

Here are both approaches in [replit](https://replit.com/@PaulStickney/IrresponsibleFrillyRectangle#main.lua).